# Play Music showing 'wrong' storage usage?

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd, 6.0-marshmallow, google-play-music

I'm running Marshmallow and I have 4GB internal storage, 32GB SD card. My SD card is formatted as 'internal storage', so Play Music won't allow me to change the destination of downloaded music from the phone's internal storage. As a result, I manually copied the mp3 files from my computer to the **SD card** via USB, and Play Music recognised them and allowed me to play them offline.

[image: Screenshot of the Manage Downloads screen]

However, when I go to the 'manage downloads' in Music settings, it shows that Play Music is using 2GB in the **internal storage** even though no music is stored in the internal storage. The black section below normally details the downloaded albums, but this is blank.

Can anyone offer any explanation for this behaviour?